Spring Jpa returning a list of objects instead of putting objects in list
I have two distinct table
    @Data
    @Entity    
    public class Person {
          @id
          Long id;  
          String name;
          Long aCommonId;
     }

And another table:
    @Data    
    @Entity
    public class PhoneNumber {
          @id
          Long id;  
          String phoneNumber;
          Long aCommonId;
     }

I'm trying with projection to have a DTO like this:
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class DTO {
          
          Person person;
          List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
     }

I have a Jpa Query
@Query("SELECT p AS person, a AS phoneNumbers FROM Person AS p JOIN FETCH PhoneNumber a ON (p.aCommonId = a.aCommonId AND p.aCommonId = :commonId)")
DTO getDTO(@Param("commonId") Long common Id);

that retrieve correctly the data based on "aCommonId" (there are no "officially" relationship between tables neither in Entity class) but hibernate instead of putting multiple PhoneNumber in the List, is returning a List of DTO with the same person and a List with one PhoneNumber.
How to tell Spring JPA to put PhoneNumber in the list?

Add your query to the question please as well as json format of a response you are getting

I updated the question. Thanks for your help

you can create the single DTO by yourself once you retrieve what you want.
Check the method down below.
Note that I've changed the query and that I'm using an EntityManager instead.
@Repository

public class CustomPersonRepository {
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public DTO getDTO(Long commonId) {
    String sql = "SELECT p, a FROM Person p JOIN PhoneNumber a ON p.aCommonId = a.aCommonId WHERE p.aCommonId = :commonId";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("commonId", commonId);
    List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();

    if (results.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Person person = (Person) results.get(0)[0];
    List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = results.stream()
                                            .map(result -> (PhoneNumber) result[1])
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new DTO(person, phoneNumbers);
}

}
